# Print parent child category path in "/" format like "parentCatId/childCatId/subChildCatId/so on"

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I want to print category path in "/" format like "parentCatId/childCatId/subChildCatId/so on". 
I want to print all parent child categoryId in single path format.

```
$cats = array(
    array("catId" => 1, "parentId" => 0),
    array("catId" => 2, "parentId" => 1),
    array("catId" => 3, "parentId" => 1),
    array("catId" => 4, "parentId" => 2),
    array("catId" => 5, "parentId" => 2),
    array("catId" => 6, "parentId" => 3),
    array("catId" => 7, "parentId" => 3),
    array("catId" => 8, "parentId" => 4),
);

function getCatIdByParent($catArr, $catId, $catPath="/") {
   $parentCatId = $catArr[$catId]['parentId'];
   if($parentCatId == 0) {
       $catPath .= $catId."/";
       return $catPath;
   } else {
       $catPath .= $catId."/";
       $a = getCatIdByParent($catArr, $parentCatId, $catPath);
   }
   return $a;
}
foreach($cats as $catInfo) {
   $catArr[$catInfo['catId']] = $catInfo;
}
foreach($catArr as $catId => $catInfo) {
   $catArr2[] = getCatIdByParent($catArr, $catId);
}
```

This gives out :

```
Array
(
    [0] => /1/
    [1] => /2/1/
    [2] => /3/1/
    [3] => /4/2/1/
    [4] => /5/2/1/
    [5] => /6/3/1/
    [6] => /7/3/1/
    [7] => /8/4/2/1/
)
```

But I want to bellow output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /5/2/1/
    [1] => /6/3/1/
    [2] => /7/3/1/
    [3] => /8/4/2/1/
)
```

Comment: do you want the output of for example [0] to be [0] = /1/2/5/ ? cuz now you start printing the sub sub children first?

Comment: you are calling function for every index that's the reason for eight outputs

Comment: @sietse85 yes! i want to print output like [0] = /1/2/5 or [0] = /5/2/1/ any.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make the 'rootParents' (0,1,2,3) as seperate indexes, with their id being the key, you then can use the 'outter' array keys as the rootParentID's and you get the wanted result.

Example:

```
$catsParents[0] = array(
                    array("catId" => 1, "parentId" => 0),
                    array("catId" => 2, "parentId" => 1),
                  );

$catsParents[1] = array (etc

foreach($catParents as $parent){
$parentId = key($parent);
// do your magic

}
```